# Confusing assumption in exercise: $a^n=b^n$, $a^m=b^m$ implies $a=b$ in [integral domain, ring with no zero divisors]

Tags: abstract-algebra

My textbook gives the following exercise: let $a$ and $b$ be elements in an integral domain $R$. If $(m,n)=1$, show that $a^n=b^n$ and $a^m=b^m$ implies $a=b$. Then it asks the same thing, with 'integral domain' replaced by 'ring where $xy=0$ implies $x=0$ or $y=0$'. The proofs given in both cases are different, though I don't understand why, and I don't understand why the conditions on the ring are necessary.

Here is an attempt at proving this for an arbitrary ring: since $(m,n)=1$ we have $nu+mv=1$ for some $u,v$. Then $a=a^{nu+mv}=a^{n^u}a^{m^{v}}=b^{n^u}b^{m^v}=b^{nu+mv}=b$. This is the proof they give for the case where $R$ is an integral domain, but it's different from the one where $R$ is not. I don't understand where I'm using this assumption here.

Comment: You seem to believe that $\,a^{nu}=a^{n^u}\;$ ...This is false. What is true is $\,a^{nu}=\left(a^n\right)^u\;$ . And all the time we're assuming the ring is commutative, right?

Comment: I think I see the reason that in "the other case" the demonstration is different: it seems to be that in that case the ring isn't assumed to have multiplicative unit!

Comment: When $nu + mv = 1$, if $m$ and $n$ are both positive, then one of $u$ and $v$ is negative (unless one of $m,\, n$ is $1$). So unless $a^n$ (or $a^m$) is a unit, you don't have $a^{nu}a^{mv}$.

Comment: @DanielFisher: Oh! I understand now. Thank you. Submit this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: In a ring with zero divisors, you can have $a^n = 0 = b^n$ without $a = b$. So the absence of zero divisors is necessary to prove the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $(m, n) = 1$, there are $c, d$ such that $cm + dn = 1$. However, one of $c, d$ is negative.  Assume that it is $d$, and let $e = |d|$, so $cm = 1 + en$. The equations below require associativity only.

$$
\begin{aligned}
a^m &= b^m \\
a^{cm} &= b^{cm}\\
a^{en+1} &=b^{en + 1}\\
a^n &= b^n\\
a^{en} &= b^{en}\\
ab^{en} &= bb^{en}\\
(a-b) b^{en} &= 0
\end{aligned}
$$
If $R$ has no zero divisors, then either $b = 0$, or $a=b$.  But $b=0$ implies $a = 0$.